# Use Of JQuery Remove Causing "Undefined" Error

Tags: jquery, append

I have added a plugin called scrollpaper to a site I'm working on. The plugin is used on both static pages, and on html snippets I append to the site.

The problem is, when the appended snippets which call the function are removed, using:

```
$(this).remove();
```

I get the following error relating to the scrollpaper plugin:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.clearer')
```

The error occurs the moment the snippets are removed. It doesn't cause any actual performance problems, and the plugin is still successfully called and executed when I re-append the snippets, but the errors do stack up, and I'd very much like to fix them.

The main plugin file is included at the foot of every page, with a call made for the static pages added below it:

```
<script src="js/jquery.scrollbarpaper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.scrollpaper-trigger').scrollbarPaper();
});
</script>
```

A second call is added to the appended html:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.scrollpaper-trigger-lightbox').scrollbarPaper();
});
</script>
```

How To Recreate The Problem:

1. Open web inspector/fire bug
2. Launch either the full, party, set menu or the reserve online form
3. Either close the opened element by clicking on the overlay/close button, or switch between the menus at the bottom of the menu page.
4. This will trigger the error

To fix the problem myself, I've so far tried only adding the base plugin file to the appended elements (and ignoring the static pages), I've also tried using `.html('')` and `.empty('')`. In place of `.remove()`, but that hasn't helped.

I've only been working with JQuery for a couple of months, so whilst I'm becoming familiar with how it all works, and I'm keen to learn best practices. However, this problem is beyond me at present, so any and all help would be hugely appreciated.

Menu Flipping Script:

```
$('.other-menus a').click(function() {
var url = $(this).attr('data-url'); 

$('.switch').fadeOut(500,
function() {
$(this).detach();
$('<div></div>').load(url).fadeIn(800).appendTo('.switch-wrap');

})

});
```

Comment: +1 for wanting to solve even non-blocking problems. Have you tried temporarily removing Scrollpaper and seeing if your errors still occur?

Comment: Cheers, it's always best to understand why something is giving out errors, as you never know when it will rear it's head as something more serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the element from the DOM using `.remove`, but this will clear all `.data` items, including the object stored at the `"scrollPaper"` key. The scrollpaper plugin is accessing properties on the object retrieved from `.data("scrollPaper")`, so when it starts returning `undefined` it throws an exception.

You want `.detach` instead in `scripts.js`:

```
$(this).detach(); //Removes Element From DOM
```

Comment: This is absolutely the root of the problem! Thanks so much for the explanation. One small bug has appeared though, I've changed the method in both scripts.js and menu.js, and whilst closing the lightbox now fixes the problem, navigating through the menu's throws up duplicate content if you click through them more than once. Any ideas, I've uploaded the updated version to the same address.

I've updated the OP with the menu flipping script.

Comment: @Dave: I'm sorry - could you elaborate on how to reproduce? As a side note, your website is rather CPU intensive. It's eating up 10% of my CPU when the website is idle; you might want to look into that as well...

Comment: Cheers for the heads up. It's using a lot of CSS3 animations, so I'll see about toning that down where possible.

To replicate the problem, launch any of the menu options in the side bar (full, set, party). On the bottom right of the menu, you have the option to toggle through other menus, and it's here that it's creating a lot of duplicate content within the div that should be updated. Thanks for sticking with it. :)

Comment: @Dave: Somehow, other children of `.switch-wrap` do not get removed so you end up with multiple `.switch` divs inside. Try `$(".switch-wrap").empty()` before you append the new one.

Comment: Added that, and it has indeed fixed the html from repeating, however if you look in the console whilst switching between menus, you'll see that it's fetching menu.js several times, rising incrementally with every subsequent click... weird!

I've uploaded a fresh version, but you've been more than generous with your time, so I don't want to impede on you further. Of course if you have any suggestions, I'll gladly listen to them. :)

Comment: @Dave: You seem to be loading the `menu.js` file inside the file you're loading using `.load`. So you're adding an extra click handler every time you call `.load`. You could use jQuery's event delegation system, so that you only have one listener at all times, which works even if elements are added later on.

Comment: Okay, I shall look into that, as I am indeed loading the js file in the appended file. Huge thanks for all your help though, have a good one. :)